# Coefficient perturbations of polynomials with real roots only

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, polynomials, computer-algebra, perturbation

Let 
\begin{align}
P(x) &= x^n+a_{n-1} x^{n-1} +\ldots+a_0 = \prod_{i=1}^n (x-p_i)\\
Q(x) &= x^n + b_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \ldots +b_0 = \prod_{i=1}^n (x-q_i)\\
p_i, q_i& \in \mathbb{R},\ 0<p_i,q_i<1  
\end{align}
 be 2 univariate polynomials such that $min_{i \neq j}|p_i-p_j|,\ min_{i\neq j}|q_i-q_j| \geq \delta$.

I am aware of general bounds for perturbations of the coefficients such those stated [here](http://imajna.oxfordjournals.org/content/20/2/185.abstract) and in Theorem 19.1 of [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.123.3313&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper, which state that if $max_i|a_i-b_i| \leq 2^{-nl + \mathcal{O}(1)}$ then $max_i|p_i-q_i| \leq 2^{-l}$. I was wondering whether the fact that $P, Q$ have only distinct real roots lying in $(0,1)$ would help decrease the necessary presicion of the coefficients.